# Объясните на пальцах про stencil(трафарет) в webgl

Tags: javascript, html5, opengl, графика, webgl

С opengl, можно сказать, не знаком. Делаю проектик на webgl рендером в 2д, на подобие pixi, но проект очень простой и тащить большой фрэймворк не нужно. Появилась необходимость разобраться глубже.

Все рендериться, кроме элементов, которые нужно обрезать.
В данный момент нужно сделать маску.
Из англоязычной доки понял, что логичнее всего реализовывать это через stencil.
Но простых примеров с минимум кода, не нагуглил.

Набросайте пожалуйста пример с квадратом и треугольником.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается, чем другие туториалы вам непонятны?

Comment: Я не понимаю как это использовать. Простых примеров не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

В **WebGL**(да и в других графических API) **stencil** буфер (буфер **трафарета**) это структура, размером с `gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHieght` которая предназначена для наложения маски (трафарета).

Можно сказать что это такая текстура. Размерность каждого пикселя в ней 8 бит.

Для того, чтобы активировать **stencil** необходимо создать `webgl` контекст с указанием соответствующей опции:

```
canvas.getContext('webgl', {stencil:true})
```

Затем, необходимо включить **stencil test**

```
gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
```

Далее что-то в этот буфер нарисовать, укажем настройки формирования трафарета и вызовем **draw**:

```
...
gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.REPLACE);
gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xff);
gl.useProgram(stencilProgram);
...
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

И потом уже, использовать трафарет во время **draw call**, тут тоже нужно указать как интерпретировать то, что находится в буфере трафарета. В результате, для пикселей, в которых в трафарете нет маски, фрагментный шейдер вызван не будет.

```
...
gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 1, 0xff);
gl.useProgram(kaliProgram);
...
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Вот пример, рисовать квадрат и треугольник, как предлагал автор, это скучно, поэтому, тут используется 3 шейдера, из них составлено 2 программы каждая рисует один треугольник, который закрывает все пиксели экрана

---

Первая формирует трафарет в виде фрактала:

[image: stencil]

---

Вторая собственно фрактал **Kali** но суть вовсе не во фракталах.

[image]

---

Суть в том что информация, которая записана в буфер трафарета используется для наложения маски на **последующий вызов draw**. Вот что из этого всего получилось:

[image: image+stencil]

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {stencil:true}) || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', {stencil:true});
  var h = gl.drawingBufferHeight;
  var w = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  let stencilProgram = program('stencil');
  let stencilCoords = gl.getAttribLocation(stencilProgram, "coords");
  let mr = gl.getUniformLocation(stencilProgram, 'mr');  

  let kaliProgram = program('kali');
  let kaliCoords = gl.getAttribLocation(stencilProgram, "coords");
  let mr1 = gl.getUniformLocation(kaliProgram, 'mr');  
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);

  draw();

  function draw(e) {
    let ev = e && e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
    let x = ev ? ev.clientX : 250;
    let y = ev ? h - ev.clientY: 111;

    gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
 
    gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.REPLACE);
    gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xff);

    gl.useProgram(stencilProgram);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(stencilCoords, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(stencilCoords);
    gl.uniform4f(mr, x, y, w, h);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    

    gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 1, 0xff);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(kaliCoords, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(kaliCoords);
    gl.useProgram(kaliProgram);
    gl.uniform4f(mr1, x, y, w, h);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    
    gl.flush();
  }

  function program(namePart) {
     let pid = gl.createProgram();
     shader('glsl/vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
     shader('glsl/fragment-' + namePart, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
     gl.linkProgram(pid);
     return pid;
    
     function shader(name, type) {
       let src = [].slice.call(document.scripts).find(s => s.type === name).innerText;
       let sid = gl.createShader(type);
       gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
       gl.compileShader(sid);
       gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
     }
  }
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<script type='glsl/vertex'>
  attribute vec2 coords;
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<script type='glsl/fragment-stencil'>precision highp float;
   uniform vec4 mr;
   void main(void) {
     vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
     vec2 q = (p + p - mr.ba) / mr.b;
     for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) -  mr.xy/mr.zw;
     }
     if (q.x<0.7)
       discard;
   }
</script>

<script type='glsl/fragment-kali'>precision highp float;
   uniform vec4 mr;
   void main(void) {
     vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
     vec2 q = (p + p - mr.ba) / mr.b;
     for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
          q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) -  mr.xy/mr.zw;
     }
     gl_FragColor = vec4(q, q.x/q.y, 1.0);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Я залип на примере)

Comment: @doox911 https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/XGXbdv вот тут проще циферки менять

Comment: @Stranger in the Q ещё красивей смотрится!