# Использование буфера трафарета (stencil buffer) в three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Пытаюсь создать сцену с применением буфера трафарета, но к сожалению, по его использованию слишком мало информации и примеров.
Планирую по центру каждой из сторон тэтраэдра вырезать круг или квадрат, это не важно.
Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать, если можно поподробнее?

Ожидаемый результат на картинке, где окружности это вырезанные отверстия.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С добавлением webGL stencil

```
    window.onload = function() {
    // Создаем переменную канвас
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var scene, camera, renderer;


    // -------------- Создание объекта - сцена ----------------
    // Создание элемента сцена
    scene = new THREE.Scene();


    // -------------- Создание объекта - источник света ----------------
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);

    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light1);


    // -------------- Создание объекта - камера ----------------
    // Создание элемента камера с углом обхора 65 градусов и пропорций и близкость и дальность отображения объекта
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);


    // -------------- Создание объекта - рендерер ----------------
    // Канва: канва - это настройка того, что функция будет передана в имеющийся элемент канвас, и не будет создаваться новый
    // antialias: true - это опция сглаживания углов у объектов
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true, alpha: true, stencil: true});
    // установка серого цвета на канвасе
    renderer.setClearColor(0x444444);
    // Устанавливаем соотношение пикселей устройства. Это обычно используется для устройства HiDPI, чтобы предотвратить размывание выходного холста.
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Установка сцены на всё окно 
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    // -------------- Создание объекта - тэтраэдр ----------------
    var tetrahedron = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry( 100, 0 );
    var tetrahedronMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0xF3FFE2, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5} );
    var tetrahedronMesh = new THREE.Mesh( tetrahedron, tetrahedronMaterial );
    tetrahedronMesh.position.set(-150, 0, -1000);
    scene.add( tetrahedronMesh );

    // -------------- Создание объекта - сфера (трафарет буфер) ----------------
    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 32 );
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0x000000, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5} );
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, sphereMaterial );
    sphereMesh.position.set(-150, 0, -1000);
    scene.add( sphereMesh );


    // -------------- Создание объекта - цилиндр ----------------
    var cylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 25, 25, 75, 32 );
    var cylinderMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0x228B22, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true} );
    var cylinderMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cylinder, cylinderMaterial );
    cylinderMesh.position.set( 100, 0, -1000);
    scene.add( cylinderMesh );


    // -------------- Создание объекта - тор ----------------
    var torus = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 31, 7, 16, 100 );
    var torusMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0xADFF2F, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5} );
    var torusMesh = new THREE.Mesh( torus, torusMaterial );
    torusMesh.position.set( 100, 0, -1000);
    torusMesh.rotation.x = 1.6;
    scene.add( torusMesh );

    // Установка позиции камера x, y, z
    camera.position.z = 300;



    // Создание функции анимация
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        tetrahedronMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        tetrahedronMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        // cylinderMesh.rotation.z += 0.01;
        // cylinderMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        cylinderMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;

        torusMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        // torusMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    animate();
}
```

Немного модернизировал свой код, добавив объект - сфера, который планируется использовать как трафарет.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Создаем переменную канвас
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var scene, camera, renderer, backStencilScene;
    var gl = renderer;


    // -------------- Создание объекта - сцена ----------------
    // Создание элемента сцена
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    backStencilScene  = new THREE.Scene();


    // -------------- Создание объекта - источник света ----------------
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);

    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light1);


    // -------------- Создание объекта - камера ----------------
    // Создание элемента камера с углом обхора 65 градусов и пропорций и близкость и дальность отображения объекта
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);


    // -------------- Создание объекта - рендерер ----------------
    // Канва: канва - это настройка того, что функция будет передана в имеющийся элемент канвас, и не будет создаваться новый
    // antialias: true - это опция сглаживания углов у объектов
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true, alpha: true, stencil: true});

    // установка серого цвета на канвасе
    renderer.setClearColor(0x444444);
    // Устанавливаем соотношение пикселей устройства. Это обычно используется для устройства HiDPI, чтобы предотвратить размывание выходного холста.
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Установка сцены на всё окно 
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    // -------------- Создание объекта - тэтраэдр ----------------
    var tetrahedron = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry( 100, 0 );
    var tetrahedronMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0xF3FFE2, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5} );
    var tetrahedronMesh = new THREE.Mesh( tetrahedron, tetrahedronMaterial );
    tetrahedronMesh.position.set(-150, 0, -1000);
    scene.add( tetrahedronMesh );

    // -------------- Создание объекта - сфера (трафарет буфер) ----------------
    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 32 );
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0x000000, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5} );
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, sphereMaterial );
    sphereMesh.position.set(-150, 0, -1000);

    // -------------- Создание объекта - цилиндр ----------------
    var cylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 25, 25, 75, 32 );
    var cylinderMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0x228B22, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true} );
    var cylinderMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cylinder, cylinderMaterial );
    cylinderMesh.position.set( 100, 0, -1000);
    backStencilScene.add( cylinderMesh );


    // -------------- Создание объекта - тор ----------------
    var torus = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 31, 7, 16, 100 );
    var torusMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0xADFF2F, roughness: 0.5, metalness: 0.5} );
    var torusMesh = new THREE.Mesh( torus, torusMaterial );
    torusMesh.position.set( 100, 0, -1000);
    torusMesh.rotation.x = 1.6;
    scene.add( torusMesh );

    // Установка позиции камера x, y, z
    camera.position.z = 300;



    // Создание функции анимация
    function animate() {
        renderer.clear();
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        // Включение буфера трафарета
        gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
        // Настройка теста
        gl.stencilFunc(
            gl.ALWAYS,    // the test
            1,            // reference value
            0xFF          // mask
        );
        // Установление трафарета на эталонное значение, когда пройдут тесты трафарета и глубины
        gl.stencilOp(
            gl.KEEP,     // что делать если тест трафарета не пройден
            gl.KEEP,     // что делать если тест глубины не пройден
            gl.REPLACE   // что делать если оба теста не пройдены
        );
        scene.add( sphereMesh );
        // Тест пройдёт только если он равен нулю
        gl.stencilFunc(
            gl.EQUAL,     // Тест
            0,            // Исходная величина
            0xFF         // Маска
        );
        gl.stencilOp(
            gl.KEEP,     // что делать если тест трафарета не пройден
            gl.KEEP,     // что делать если тест глубины не пройден
            gl.KEEP      // что делать если оба теста не пройдены
        );




        tetrahedronMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        tetrahedronMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        // cylinderMesh.rotation.z += 0.01;
        // cylinderMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        cylinderMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;

        torusMesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        // torusMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }

    animate();
}
```

Comment: А можно предоставить картинку с ожидаемым результатом?

Comment: Картинку добавил к вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, что правильно понял поставленный вопрос :)

Отверстия разных форм в гранях тетраэдра можно сделать с помощью формообразующей функции по UV координатам.

Функция взята [отсюда](https://thebookofshaders.com/07/). Была так же применена [в этом примере](https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/rNBXVmb?editors=0010).

Трюк здесь в том, чтобы использовать свойство материала `.alphaTest`. В шейдере задаем для нужных нам фрагментов прозрачность 0, а дальше код шейдера материала сам уберет те фрагменты, для которых значение прозрачности `.a` меньше `0.5`.

На всякий случай тут вот ссылка на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/jodt7ufx/).

Собственно, пример решения:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.set(0.5, 1, 2);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
//renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(2, 4, 0x404040, 0x404040));

// tetrahedron

var pts = [
  new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(8 / 9), 0, -(1 / 3)),
  new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2 / 9), Math.sqrt(2 / 3), -(1 / 3)),
  new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2 / 9), -Math.sqrt(2 / 3), -(1 / 3)),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)
];

var faces = [
  pts[0].clone(), pts[2].clone(), pts[1].clone(),
  pts[0].clone(), pts[1].clone(), pts[3].clone(),
  pts[1].clone(), pts[2].clone(), pts[3].clone(),
  pts[2].clone(), pts[0].clone(), pts[3].clone()
];

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(faces);
geom.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);

geom.setAttribute("uv", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([
  0.5, 1, 0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001,
  0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001, 0.5, 1,
  0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001, 0.5, 1,
  0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001, 0.5, 1
], 2));

var matPts = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.1,
  color: "red"
});
var points = new THREE.Points(geom, matPts);
scene.add(points);

var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg"),
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  alphaTest: 0.5
});
mat.defines = {
  USE_UV: ""
};
var uniforms = {
  vSides: {
    value: 5
  }
};
mat.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
  console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  shader.uniforms.vSides = uniforms.vSides;
    shader.fragmentShader = `
   uniform float vSides;
    ` + shader.fragmentShader;
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `#include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>`,
    `#include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>

float getShape(float outer, vec2 uv){
    uv *= 2.0;
    float a = atan(uv.x,-uv.y);
    float r = 3.1415926 * 2. / vSides;
    float d = cos( floor( .5 + a / r ) * r - a ) * length( uv );
    return step(outer, d);
}
`
  );
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );`,
    `vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );
    diffuseColor.a = getShape(0.25, vUv - 0.5);
    `
  );
}
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
scene.add(mesh);


renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

PS Построил свой тетраэдр с гранями и UV координатами, так как мне нужно было точно знать, что UV координаты заданы так, как мне надо. Координаты точек взяты из [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Coordinates_for_a_regular_tetrahedron). UV координаты нашел сам, главное, чтобы UV c величинами `[0.5, 0.5]` находилась в центре грани. Количество сторон для отверстий задается в этой униформе:

```
var uniforms = {
  vSides: {
    value: 5
  }
};
```

Comment: А ведь наверное можно было не морочиться с uv крординатами, а посчитать дистанции до мировых координат, найденных интерполяцией координат вершин, наверное

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я сперва тоже об этом подумал, глядя на окружности. А потом приуныл как-то, подумав, что нужно сделать, чтобы получить правильные полигоны с учетом наклона отдельно взятой грани :) А тут - по UV координатам - всегда по плоскости - всяко удобнее. Да и сами UV координаты для правильного треугольника, совмещенного центром с центром квадрата 2х2, посчитать не трудно.

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш пример не подходит, у меня конкретное задание использовать stencil buffer для вырезания этих дырок. Я нашел пример по его использованию https://codepen.io/mattari-panda/pen/LRAmOg?editors=0010 но пока не могу разобраться как его адаптировать под своё задание.

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov Чистое любопытство: это домашнее или тестовое задание?

Comment: @prisoner849 Курсовая работа, мне осталось только применить буфер трафарета :)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что никто не знает как это использовать?

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov буфер трафарета это маска, которая применяется ко всем пикселям при отрисовке примитива. для того чтобы применить буфер трафарета, вам необходимо определить область экрана, где при отрисовки одной грани должно быть отверстие.

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov вот в этот ответ использует трафарет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950855/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, я видел этот пример но он на webGL. Вообщем, если в рамках three это сделать невозможно, хотя, в доке упоминание о трафарете есть. Я попробовал разобраться и использовать код из этого примера, но что-то получаю ошибку с определением функции stancil. Пример получившегося кода добавил к вопросу.

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov я попробую собрать на three.js попозже

Comment: Если вдруг интересно, то `renderer.state.setStencilFunc()` теперь `renderer.state.buffers.stencil.setFunc()`. И все остальные функции - по тому же пути `renderer.state.buffers.stencil`.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Не уверен, что там хоть что-то правильно, но, может, на какие мысли натолкнет :) https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/18h25sat/ Вдохновлялся вот этим: https://sites.google.com/site/cgwith3js/home/masking-with-stencil

Comment: @prisoner849 попытался адаптировать Ваш пример к своей работе, однако остались вопросы к  обявелнию методов трафарета в функции animate, как Вы написали просто добавляем в функцию state.buffer, я так попробовал, не сработало, вероятно для renderer эти функции имеют другие названия. Плюс есть вопрос к объявлению переменной var gl = renderer.context; её теперь объявлять как var gl = renderer?

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov `.setStencilFunc()` => `.buffers.stencil.setFunc()`. Можно сделать `console.log(renderer.state)` и посмотреть структуру свойства `buffers`.